# How to reverse a list using only three functions

Tags: list, function, reverse

If I am given three functions:
1) empty - returns whether a passed list is empty
2) split - splits one list into two equal sized lists
3) concat - concatenates two lists into one

Using only these three functions, how can I reverse a list?

Comment: This sounds like homework, so you might want to tag it as such. Aside from that, what does `split` do when used on a list with only one item?

Comment: I guess splitting one element list returns an empty list, and a list with one item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split list in two, recursively reverse sublists, and merge them backwards.

```
def reverse(x) {
    y, z = split(x)
    if (empty(y) || empty(z)) 
        return x // list has only one element
    else
        return concat(reverse(z), reverse(y))

}
```

Comment: I don't really understand recursion very well, can you explain how this works?

Comment: Sure. Basically we divide our problem (reversing a list) into two smaller problems (reversing a shorter list), solve those subproblems, and use partial solutions to answer original problem. We reverse our shorter lists using the same algorithm - we split them, reverse the sublists, etc, up to the point when we try to reverse a one element list; as such a list is equal to itself reversed, we simply return it without any other changes. Splitting a list with more than one element always returns two shorter lists, so we're sure to reach a case with one-element list - and so, recursion always ends.